# 32-bit oracle 10g client to 64-bit oracle 10g server

Tags: oracle10g

Due to a 3rd party application's requirement, I may be forced to use 32-bit client of Oracle 10gR2 on the application server to connect to a 64-bit DB server oracle 10gR2 (10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit;another box). The OS is SUSE Linux ver 10. Platform is x86.
There are no problems connecting to 64-bit DB server via 32-bit client. I have tested this.

- Does this result in performance degradation? Does Oracle or anyone else has any recommendations about this kind of scenario? Searched the net without much gain.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem at all in Oracle, the client works fine with any server (32-bit or 64-bit or big-endian or little-endian, whatever). What makes you worry? We aren't in 90s anymore ;)